# MapFragment - The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, mapfragment

I was having the following error

```
Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Researched about it... Made sure everything started in new threads as much as possible with Runnables. But kept getting the error. I almostly commented all my code and still got it when I started a new activity. Then I commented this mapfragment from my first activity and there error was gone. **So the error is caused by following piece of code:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />
```

I got this from Google Maps API for Android docs... Kind of weird it's not optimised. How can I make sure the error disappears? Can I delay the load of the mapFragment?

Once I opened the Activity once... and reopen it again the warning is gone because it's in the memory already.. but I'd like to have the best optimised app possible.

**To avoid confusion** It's the setContentView that is causing delay because the mapFragment is loaded in this function. The delay causes a warning to be thrown. My question: how can I speed up the setContentView, so the mapFragment is pre-loaded or loads after the activity is opened.

Comment: There is no code running. Not a single line. Only the load of the views, it's the fragment xml that causes the warning. If I uncomment the code then all my code is in different threads and one is in an AsyncTask so that's okay.

Comment: if you show your java code i can help you

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna it's a closed source project. I can only show the part I'm showing right now. There is no code to show. Make a new empty project, put a mapfragment in (just the code pasted above) and you'll see that it gives too much work on main thread warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) you can set up listener for when GoogleMap is ready

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {  
...  
}  
@Override  
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[setContentView() slow with map fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418927/setcontentview-slow-with-map-fragment)

This contains the answer. Was deeply down hidden in Google, but found it!